# Ingresar datos por teclado y mandarlas como parametros al constructor

Tags: java

Mi consulta se debe a que quiero pedir al usuario que ingrese por teclado
los datos del alumno, y luego usar los parametros ingresados para mandarlas al  constructor Alumno. Cual es la forma de hacer esto?

## Alumno.java

```
public class Alumno {

    private String nom = "null";
    private String ap = "null";
    private String dni = "null";
    private String tel = "null";

    public Alumno(String nom,String ap, String dni, String tel){
        this.nom = nom;
        this.ap = ap;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public void mostrarAlum(){
        System.out.println("Alumno: "+nom+" Apellido: "+ape+" DNI: "+dni+"  Telefono: "+tel);
    }
}
```

## EjercicioModelarObjetos.java

```
package ejerciciomodelarobjetos;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 *
 * @autor jorge
 */
public class EjercicioModelarObjetos {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Ingresee los datos correspondientes:");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //System.out.print("Nombre:");
        Alumno alu = new Alumno(nom, ap, dni, tel);
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor incluye el código directamente en lugar de poner imágenes

Comment: Gracias Carlos por la modificación, de apoco voy poniéndome al corriente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java cuenta con la clase [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
//Inicializamos el escáner
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

//Pedimos los datos del estudiante
System.out.print("Ingresa nombre del alumno: ");
String studentName = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.print("Ingresa apellido del alumno: ");
String studentLastname = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.print("Ingresa dni del alumno: ");
String studentDni = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.print("Ingresa teléfono del alumno: ");
String studentPhone = scanner.nextLine();

//Aquí llamamos al constructor
Alumno alumno = new Alumno(studentName, studentLastname, studentDni, studentPhone);
```

Así es como pides datos desde el teclado en la terminal.

Comment: No sabia que estaba la clase scanner aparte del BufferedReader para la entrada de datos, gracias por hacérmelo saber, parece mucho mas simple.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que crear un programa que pida los datos y una vez recuperados, invoque al constructor.

El cómo pedir los datos al usuario variará dependiendo del tipo de programa que utilices.

El siguiente código es un ejemplo de una aplicación de consola (simplificada).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Program {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Introduzca Nombre ");
    String nombre = reader.readLine();
    //... lo mismo para las demás propiedades

    Alumno alum = new Alumno(nombre,apellido, dni, telefono);
    alum.mostrarAlum();
   }
}
```

Comment: Así justamente lo venia haciendo, te lo agradezco Javier, ya me quedo mas tranquilo.

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar la clase [**`javax.swing.JOptionPane`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) para permitir al usuario introducir los datos correspondientes. Ejemplo:

```
// Entrada de datos
String nom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre:");
String ape = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Apellido:");
String dni = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("DNI:");
String tel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Teléfono:");

// Se crea la instancia de Alumno
Alumno alumno = new Alumno(nom, ape, dni, tel);
```

Comment: Muy bueno!!  cual es la diferencia entre la clase javax.swing.JOptionPane y las otras dos?

Comment: En este caso concreto creo que Swing está demás. @JorgeGonzalez es una clase de la librería estándar de Java para pedir datos a través de una interfaz de usuario.